# How to factorize bi-quadratic

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I came across this question and have no idea how to factorise this. How can $x^4+4$ be factorised?

Comment: is there a formula for this?

Comment: $x^4 + 4 = (x^2 - 2 x + 2) (x^2 + 2 x + 2)$

Comment: can i know how to get that?

Comment: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ so $x^4 + 4 = (x^2 - 2i)(x^2 + 2i) = (x - (1+i))(x+(1+i))(x - (1-i))(x + (1-i))$ to factor completely, then $x^2 - 2x + 2 = (x - (1-i))(x - (1+i))$ and $x^2 + 2x + 2 = (x + (1+i)) (x + (1-i))$

Comment: thank you for being helpfullll

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it can be factored in high school:
$$x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2+2-2x)(x^2+2+2x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the Quadratic Formula $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
solves $ax^2+bx+c=0$ just as $$x^2=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
solves $ax^4+bx^2+c=0$.

Thus apply it for $a=1,b=0,c=4$

Comment: You can then use that solution to factorise it.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why?